# Keep UIScrollView in correct place after switching from landscape to portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains a text field and a text view. I have code to move the text fields up when the keyboard is present so the keyboard does not cover the text fields. This code works great in portrait view:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return NO;
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.nameField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,   (self.view.frame.origin.y - 90), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.nameField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 90), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField {
    if (textField == self.questionField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y - 200), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textField {
    if (textField == self.questionField) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 200), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

When I rotate the iPhone simulator into a landscape view, this (not surprisingly) does not work. How can I get the text field to move up just enough to see it while typing into it in both landscape and portrait views?

Also, if I rotate from landscape to portrait while the keyboard is shown, after dismissing the keyboard the scroll view has moved down the screen instead of lined up in its original position. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's document [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) shows the proper way to do this under the heading "Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard".

You basically put your content on a scroll view and use the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` notifications to adjust the content offsets.

However, the code is somewhat incomplete. The keyboard size calculation doesn't work in landscape mode. To fix it, replace this:

```
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

With this:

```
// Works in both portrait and landscape mode
CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect toView:nil];

CGSize kbSize = kbRect.size;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I have textViews and textFields in my app. This works great for the textView but does not work for the textField. Any idea as to why this is?